# Missing resources after changing faces mapping

Tags: java, jsf

I had my faces url-pattern just like this:

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/faces/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

And some image resources under META-INF/resources/images in a third-party jar. My CSS file used to reference an image like this:

```
.ui-icon16-users { background-image: url('images/icon16_users.png') !important; }
```

It used to work.

But when I changed the url-mapping to

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

all the images gone missing and I tried every URL combinations to find them.

Is there anything I'm missing after changing the url-pattern? Thanks.

Comment: Is this a Maven project ?

Comment: Yes. But I've solved the problem and in a few minutes I'll post the solution.

Answer (score 1):

All I had to do is change:

```
.ui-icon16-users { background-image: url('images/icon16_users.png') !important; }
```

to

```
.ui-icon16-users { background-image: url("#{resource['images/icon16_users.png']}") !important; }
```

I hope it can help others with the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

To change the JSF servlet Mapping always use [Prettyfaces](http://ocpsoft.org/prettyfaces/). It is independent to your resource folder. JSF resource always works with relative path in of URL. So change your CSS url as `#{resource['images/icon16_users.png']}` or  `url(resources/images/icon16_users.png')`.